# Nest JSON into "data"

Tags: php, json, laravel

I currently return JSON to ajax call in this format:
[ 
{"username":"test3","points":62,"sportName":"Basketball"},
          {"username":"test2","points":55,"sportName":"Football"} 
]

But I want it like this:
{ 
"data":
[ 
{ "username":"test3", "points":"62", "sportName":"Basketball" },
 { "username":"test2", "points":"55", "sportName":"Football" }
 ]
 }

Function that returns it (Laravel):

```
$scores=DB::select("SELECT user.username, points
                    FROM scores
                    JOIN users AS user ON user.id = scores.user_id
                    ORDER BY points DESC");

return json_encode($scores);
```

Comment: Please use the Snippet `[<>]` button and their `Tidy` Option to format your code.

Comment: do you need stringed `points`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this.

```
return json_encode( ['data' => $scores] );
```